# Many to Many relationship or fallacy?

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship

I have a table `Products`:

```
id | name | price
__________________
1    Rose    40
```

Besides there is another intermediate table that contains information for whom product is intended:

```
id | product_id | for_whom
___________________________
1     1              1
2     1              2
```

The third table is `ForWhom`:

```
id | Name
__________
1    Mom
```

Any product can contains one or more parameters `for_whom`.

Otherwise, using table `ForWhom` I can find one or more products which are associated with `ForWhom` table.

I think I need to use many-to-many relationship, but I am doubt.

What can you say?

Comment: You need to look into _joining_ tables in SQL.  This is a relatively easy question.  Try to put some effort into it.

Comment: This is classic many-to-many relationship example. Middle table is so called "bridge table". Not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I tried to set properties for each products.

Comment: Joins tables is operation, but I talk about basics - relationships.

Comment: Maybe mom needs a car, too? Or a bicycle? XOR a bottle of wine?

Comment: Yes, you are right :)

Comment: So, you tell it is many-to-many?

Comment: I don't think that this information will be useful for you, if you don't know what many-to-many means. Go read some articles about many-to-many relationships and see if it fits you case and can help you achieve your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can answer this by talking yourself through the relationship as you have above.

In the example you've given, you can express it as follows.

One Product Can Belong To One or More ForWhom.
One ForWhom Can Own One or More Product.

One of the the aims of database normalization is to prevent duplication of data.
So if you have a Product which belongs to more than one ForWhom, and you have a for_whom column in the Product table, then every time a Product belongs to more than one ForWhom, you will duplicate the product record.
Likewise, if you have a ProductID in the ForWhom table, then every time a ForWhom owns more than one Product, you will duplicate the ForWhom record.

The solution is as you've suggested above. You have an intermediary table that allows you to hold the relationship without duplicating any data.
In your solution above, every record in Product, ForWhom and ProductForWhom (intermediary table) would be unique, therefore you would not be duplicating data.